# How to make BottomSheetDialog closeable with horizontal ViewPager2/RecyclerView as content?

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout, bottom-sheet

I have a `BottomSheetDialogFragment` with `ViewPager2` (horizontal orientation) as the main content.

The sheet doesn't respond to vertical scrolls (for dismissing) as it would for a `RecyclerView` (with vertical orientation).

I tried replacing `ViewPager2` with just horizontal oriented `RecyclerView` - same behavior, so it's probably the same issue.

My simplified layout for bottom sheet fragment:

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
   <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2/>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```